# How to change the abstract to have no page break afterwards

Tags: page-breaking, titles, abstract, thesis

I am writing a thesis in the report document class.
I have a title page that is separate.
On the next page I want the Abstract and the Acknowledgements:

```
\begin{abstract}
 This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
 I would like to thank...
\end{abstract}
```

Doing that puts them on two separate pages though. How can I change the abstract environment/create a new environment that behaves in the way I want?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `titlepage` option, the `abstract` environment is defined to use a separate page.

You can do it simply by adding the acknowledgments to the abstract:

```
\begin{abstract}
 This is the abstract.

\vspace{2in} % or whatever

\begin{center}
\bfseries Acknowledgements
\end{center}

I would like to thank...
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: Thanks. Added a \noindent in front of "I would like to thank" so that it behaves like the abstract above.